# Remove an item from $form_state in an ajax callback

Tags: 8, forms

I'm using this form api example: [AjaxAddMore](https://github.com/drupalprojects/examples/blob/8.x-1.x/form_api_example/src/Form/AjaxAddMore.php). I want to add a "remove button" for each indiviaul element, in order to remove an item but not the latest. Thouse are my changes:

```
...
  $form['names_fieldset'] = [
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => $this->t('People coming to picnic'),
      '#prefix' => '<div id="names-fieldset-wrapper">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
      '#attributes' => array('class'=>array('container-inline')),
    ];

    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_names; $i++) {

      $form['names_fieldset']['fields'][$i] = [
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#name' => 'id_'.$i
      ];

      $form['names_fieldset']['fields'][$i]['ids'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => $this->t('ID'),
        '#default_value' => $i,
        '#name' => 'id_'.$i
      ];

      $form['names_fieldset']['fields'][$i]['name'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => $this->t('Name')
      ];

      $form['names_fieldset']['fields'][$i]['remove'] = [
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#name' => 'remove_'.$i,
        '#value' => $this->t('Remove this'),
        '#submit' => ['::removethisCallback'],
        '#ajax' => [
          'callback' => '::addmoreCallback',
          'wrapper' => 'names-fieldset-wrapper',
        ],
      ];
    }
....
```

It works good and I can add several records. But I can't remove an item other than the latest one. This is my callback function where I've tried to unset the item I want to remove:

```
public function removethisCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $button_clicked = $form_state->getTriggeringElement()['#name'];
    $id = substr($button_clicked,7);
    $values = $form_state->getValue(['names_fieldset']);
    unset($values[$id]);
    $form_state->setValues(['names_fieldset'], array_values($values));  

    $name_field = $form_state->get('num_names');
    if ($name_field > 1) {
        $remove_button = $name_field - 1;
        $form_state->set('num_names', $remove_button);
    }   
    $form_state->setRebuild();
}
```

But It doesn't work. How could I remove or update an item from $form_state?

Comment: `unset($values[$id]);` should be `unset($values[$ids])` because your `$form['names_fieldset']['fields'][$i]['ids']` has an "s".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't think so, because $id is a variable that hold the item index to delete. It isn't the field 'ids'. I get the item index to delete using $form_state->getTriggerElement, and then I get #name.

Comment: Ok then you don't need to `unset`, you just set a new value and that will override it.

Comment: Yes. That's what I want. But I don't find a way to do it. All changes I do over $form_state are lost.

Comment: try adding a `&` to `$form_state` in your function `removethisCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state) {` or try commenting out `$form_state->setRebuild();` I don't think you need this.

Comment: I need $form_state->setRebuild() in order to delete the input elements. If I comment out this line, the form doesn't change.

Comment: I think that explains why all changes to `$form_state` are lost.

Comment: I don't think so. When buildForm is called, I don't loose input values. They remain with values I put. What I was wondering is if I can alter $form_state in a callback function or I should alter $form. But I've tried both without success.

Comment: It is doable. Keep it simple, for testing purposes, build a form with 1 text field. In the validate function, alter the `$form_state` there. Once you get this simple scenario working add AJAX to it. Once you get that working on an ajax callback, now try it on your real world complex scenario.

Comment: I've tried it. I tried to update input value in a callback funtion, but, again, without success.

Answer (score 1):

> $form_state->setValues(['names_fieldset'], array_values($values));

**[setValues(array $values)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AsetValues/8.0.x)** only has 1 parameter

For 2 params, you need to use **[setValue($key, $value)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormStateInterface.php/function/FormStateInterface%3A%3AsetValue/8.2.x)** without the "s"

```
$form_state->setValue('name', array_values($values));
```

---

Alternatively, you could do

```
$values = $form_state->getValues();
$values['name'] = array_values($values);
$form_state->setValues($values);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, and I think I have a working solution (D9).

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state): array {
  // $form_state contains all values. Add a new item for init.
  $values = $form_state->getValues();

  if (!isset($values['persons'])) {
    $values['persons'][] = [
      'name' => '',
      'birthdate' => '',
      'btn_text' => 'remove person',
    ];
  }
}
```

An example from the `$form` build:

```
foreach ($values['persons'] as $k => $v) {
  $form['persons'][$k]['name'] = [
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Person name',
  ];
}
```

Remove btn. `#indx` is the person id param.

```
$form['persons'][$k]['remove_person'] = [
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => 'remove person',
  '#submit' => ['::removePerson'],
  '#name' => 'reove_person_' . $k,
  '#indx' => 'indx' . $k,
  '#ajax' => [
    'callback' => '::personCallback',
    'wrapper' => 'persons',
  ],
  '#suffix' => '<hr>',
];
```

Remove person callback get the person index (`#indx`), remove the item, and rebuild the `$form_state`:

```
public function removePerson(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state): void {
  $values = $form_state->getValues();
  $element = $form_state->getTriggeringElement();

  if (!isset($element['#indx'])) {
    return;
  }

  $i = preg_replace('~\D~', '', $element['#indx']);

  if (isset($values['persons'][$i])) {
    unset($values['persons'][$i]);
  }

  $form_state->setValues($values);
  $form_state->setRebuild();
}
```

person callback rebuild the form:

```
public function personCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state): array {
  return $form['persons'];
}
```